# Integral of a continuous function of l+1 variables

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals, continuity

Consider a function $f(\theta, x): \Theta \times \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $\mathcal{X} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $\Theta \subseteq \mathbb{R}^l$. Suppose the map $\theta \rightarrow f(\theta,x)$ is continuous at $\theta_0$ and that the map $x \rightarrow f(\theta_0,x)$ is integrable on $\mathcal{X}$.

I want to show that the map $\theta\rightarrow F(\theta):=\int_{\mathcal{X}} f(\theta,t)dt$ is continuous at $\theta_0$, i.e. $\lim_{\theta \rightarrow \theta_0}F(\theta)=F(\theta_0)$.

My attempt (incomplete):

(i) Assume that $\mathcal{X}:=[a,b]$.

(ii) By the fundamental theorem of Calculus, which can be applied because the map $x \rightarrow f(\theta_0,x)$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, the map $u \rightarrow G(\theta_0,u):=\int_{a}^{u}f(\theta_0,t)dt$ is continuous at each $u$ $\in [a,b]$.

(iii) This means that the map $u \rightarrow G(\theta_0,u)$ is continuous at $u=b$, i.e. $\lim_{u \rightarrow b}G(\theta_0,u)=G(\theta_0,b)$

(iv) $G(\theta_0,b)=F(\theta_0)$

(v)?

Could you specify also if the answer that you provide depends on $\mathcal{X}$ be a closed interval of $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the integrals $\int f_\theta$ to converge to $\int f_{\theta_0}$ when the argument $\theta$ converges to $\theta_0.$ This is an example of a general class of theorems about convergence of integrals.

If $f_\theta(t)$ depends continuously on $\theta$ and $t$ jointly and is constantly $0$ outside some compact region of $\mathbb R^l$ that does not depend on $\theta$ then the functions $f_\theta(t)$ converge *uniformly* to $f_{\theta_0}(t)$ and that is a sufficient condition for convergence of their integrals (the absolute difference of the integrals is bounded above by the volume of the compact region times the maximum difference between the two functions).

Another useful situation is *monotonous convergence:* if $f_{\theta_1}(t)\leq f_{\theta_2}(t)$ whenever $\theta_1<\theta_2$ then the integrals converge.

Finally, there is *dominated convergence:* if there exists an integrable function $g(t)$ such that $|f_\theta(t)|\leq g(t)$ for all $t$ and for all $\theta$ then the integrals converge.

In general there exist counterexamples when neither of these preconditions are satisfied.

Let $\chi$ be the interval $[0,1],$ $l=1$ and let $f_\theta$ be defined by a bump around $1/\theta:$ $f_\theta(t)=\max(1-|t-1/\theta|,0)$ if $\theta\neq 0,$ and $f_0(t)=0.$ Then $f_\theta(t)\to f_0(t)$ for all $t.$ The integral of $f_0$ is obviously 0 but the integrals of the other $f_\theta$ are all 1.

Note that the $f_\theta$ are not dominated by any integrable function $g:$ their lowest common upper limit is the constant 1, which is not integrable.